# for loop executes only once in editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, ios, for-loop, tableview

Code:

```
if(self.editing == YES)
{
    if(self.editing == YES && indexPath.section == 7 && indexPath.row == [[self pickGoalsFromAnd:0] count])
    {   
        NSLog(@"INSERT editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath.section: %d", (indexPath.section));
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
    }
    NSLog(@"Net voor FORLUS");
    for(int sectieId = 0; sectieId < [[self pickAnd] count]; sectieId++)
    {

        NSLog(@"Binnen FORLUS , sectieId/pickAndCount: (%d)/(%d)", sectieId, [[self pickAnd] count]);

        sectieId = sectieId + 8;
        NSLog(@"indexPath.section '==' %d '&&' indexPath.row '==' %d", sectieId , [[self pickGoalsFromAnd:(sectieId-8)] count]  );

                    if(indexPath.section == sectieId && indexPath.row < [[self pickGoalsFromAnd:(sectieId-8)] count])
                    {
                        NSLog(@"INSERT editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath.section: %d", (indexPath.section));
                    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
                    }
                    else 
                        if(indexPath.section != ([[self pickAnd] count] + 7))
                        {
                    {
                        NSLog(@"ifELSE");
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
                    }
                        }
    }
```

As I can see using NSLogs, the for-loop is only executed once. Is it possible the for loop stops when it 'returned' something ?

For loop: for(int sectieId = 0; sectieId < [[self pickAnd] count]; sectieId++)

Comment: 'return' exits the current method or function.  What else do you think it should do?  (Note also that you're modifying the loop control variable which could cause unexpected results.)

Comment: How can I convert this for-loop in something that will do the same actions as this specific for-loop? I have a variable amount of sections, so i'll need some kind of for-loop..

Comment: What do you mean by "this specific for-loop"?  What do you actually want to have happen?

Comment: put a 'plus sign', UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert, in front of every last cell of a section. The problem: there's a variable amount of sections and cells..

Answer (score 1):

Once you return, you exit the function and the lopp breaks so that's why it's only executed once.